# Where and How to park for free in Ixelles (Brussels)?

Tags: belgium

I just arrived in Brussels with my new contract and I would like to bring my car from France. However, I was wondering how to get a cheap way of parking it wihtout having to register it in Belgium. The car is at my dad name so I can't get resident parking. I was wondering if there was other ways.

If not, do you have any idea on how to find garage spaces to rent ?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: It's really not a good idea to come abroad with the car you don't own. Do you have any written documents you're allowed to posses the car?

Comment: Yes it is my dad's car

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a good idea to use a foreign-registered car in Belgium for a significant length of time. You may, for example, have problems with getting insurance for the car, either in France or in Belgium. Your current insurance may also not be valid if you are not resident in France.

In general, parking in Brussels is tough if you don't have a garage. I only drive occasionally and I've spent 30+ minutes finding a space in the past. Brussels is very congested and has a very unpleasant driving culture - if you can, it's better not to have a car and to use public transport instead.

Comment: Yes but I am insured for 3 months. Could I possibly make my car move from time to time to france.